# Newtonsoft: How to get comments while using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings())`?

Tags: json.net

Newtonsoft: How to get comments while using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings())`?

**CommentHandling** can be passed in with **JObject.Parse**, but don't see a way to pass it in to **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject**.

```
   var results = JObject.Parse("", new JsonLoadSettings
   {
       CommentHandling = CommentHandling.Load
   });
```

Comment: How does your Json string look with comments ?

Comment: Looks like you are correct.  What settings do you need to set in `JsonSerializerSettings`?  There may be a workaround for certain settings, e.g.

Comment: No longer needed. Went with a solution that doesn't require comments